# How to log user browser and separate failed and successful logins to different tables?

Tags: php, mysql, logging

I have a code that logs date, IP, username and password inputs for both failed and successful logins to a single table.

I want the failed logins logs to go to another table instead of logging all in one table. My original code is below.

I also want log which browser they are using but I don't know how to do it with PHP.

Config Login

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['username']) === false) {

    $newUsername = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']);
    $newPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']);
    $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // write the new infos to db
    $query = "INSERT INTO `userlog` (`username`, `password`, `ip`, `date`) 
        VALUE ('".$newUsername."', '".$newPassword."', '".$userIP."', '".$today."')";
    if($result = $link->query($query)) {
        // content writen
        // echo "IP FOR USERNAME ".$_POST['username'].'<br>'.PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "ERROR WRITING IN DB, SORRY ".$_POST['username'].'!<br>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```